# How can I set default application for unknown file on xdg-open / mimeopen?

Tags: desktop-environment, vlc, mime-types, xdg-open, user-default

On my Lubuntu (18.10), `xdg-open` launches VLC Player when the file is not associated to any applications.

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype jquery.js
application/javascript
$ xdg-mime query default application/javascript # no output
$ xdg-open jquery.js
Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/javascript"
Opening "/tmp/jquery.js" with VLC media player  (application/javascript)
```

On some files, it launches Calibre's E-book viewer (.rb for example).

---

**EDIT** I digged into `xdg-open` and found it executes following commands:

1. Check filetype with `xdg-mime query filename "$file"` and `xdg-mime query default $filetype`
2. `run-mailcap --action=view "$file"`
3. `mimeopen -L -n "$file"`

The problem lies in mimeopen.

Then how can I change mimeopen to open any **unknown files** with featherpad, or specific app?  In other words, I'd like to set default fallback application if mimeopen can not find any suitable apps.

Comment: 1) It looks like it's not a problem of MIME-type/application association. As you say, MIME types are recognized and a default application for them is not set. 2) Looking at `/usr/bin/xdg-open`: it looks like it's unable to detect your desktop environment. Knowing the output of `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` might help. 2.1) It looks like it's running `run-mailcap` and then `mimeopen`, (in a way that won't show you an application chooser), instead of running the file manager (pcmanfm, right?).

Comment: Thanks!  I digged into `/usr/bin/xdg-open` and confirmed that it executes `mimeopen -L -n "$file"`.  Now I'm checking `mimeopen` to find reasons why VLC is associated to these files.

Comment: If your `xdg-open` is not executing `open_lxde()` you may want to try setting the environment variable `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE`. This way `xdg-open` should try to call `pcmanfm` instead of `mimeopen` and, if you are lucky (I'm not on LXDE, cannot test reliably), the file manager could ask you how to open files that have no explicit application association set.

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu 18.10 and its DE is now LxQT.  And in `xdg-open`, `open_lxqt` is just an alias of `open_generic`.  I'll update my question based on our comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mimeopen` treats unknown files as `text/plain` or `application/octet-stream`.

To set default application, run mimeopen with `-d` option.  Since I could not find option to specify mimetype, you need to create dummy files at first.

```sh
touch text.txt # for text/plain
mimeopen -d text.txt # and choose your favorite app

echo -e \\0 > data.dat # for application/octet-stream
mimeopen -d -M data.dat
```

or edit "~/.config/mimeapps.list".

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=featherpad.desktop;  
application/octet-stream=firefox.desktop;
```

---

`mimeopen`, which is shiped with [File-MimeInfo](https://metacpan.org/release/File-MimeInfo), tries to find applications with *parent* mimytypes.  For example, if the filetype starts with "text/", it has "text/plain" as parent.  And all filetype inherits "application/octet-stream".

On mimeopen in my environment, the most "suitable" app for octet-stream is VLC Player and for text/plain, it is Calibre's E-book Viewer.  That's why some files are opened with these apps.

Comment: It seems to detect empty files as text/plain. Wouldn't it be better to set the default for application/octet-stream if that is the root of all mimetypes? At least I was able to get a file detected like that using `echo -e \\0 > filename.txt`

Comment: @JonasBerlin I added it to my answer, thanks!

Comment: application/octet-stream work for all the unknown mime types , very good information ... thanks

Answer (score 3):

From `man xdg-mime` there is an option: `xdg-mime default application mimetype(s)` to set default applications. You can use

```
xdg-mime default featherpad.desktop application/javascript
```

to  make `featherpad.desktop` as default editor for opening files like `application/javascript`.

Alternatively you can find a file under `/usr/share/applications/` directory like `default.list` depends upon file manager in my case it is `gnome-mimeapps.list` (I am having gnome DE  and nautilus FM). You can edit this file  to launch default applications.

Comment: I'm afraid but I'd like to change behavior about all unknown files, not only about javascript...

Comment: @rad164 see updated answer.